# Fetching specific data from a selected entry

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest

I am new to iOS Developing, and I'm getting my feet wet in Core Data. I've got an app that I'm slowly piecing together (thanks to help from this site!), but I'm stuck on how to fetch data.

The app:

My app has two main screens, both UITableViews: A "Class List" view where they can add new classes, and an "Add My data model has two entities: Course (for class) and Student, with a to-many relationship from Course-Student. Right now I have it working so that when a I tap on a class in the "Class List" view I am taken to the "Add Students" view where I can add students to the class, but my fetch results controller is returning all students that I have added. My question: how do I format the fetch request in the "Add Students" view to fetch only those students that should belong to that class? Here is the fetched results controller I have right now:

```
-(NSFetchedResultsController *) fetchedResultsController {
if (_fetchedResultsController !=nil) {
    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Student" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

_fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"name" cacheName:nil];
_fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
return _fetchedResultsController;
```

}

I'm guessing it has something to do with predicates, but I haven't gotten that far in my learning. Any help at all would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are guessing right. To fetch all students that belong to a particular course,
add the following predicate to the fetch request:

```
Course *theCourse = ...; // your Course object
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"course = %@", theCourse];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
```

(assuming that the to-one relationship from *Student* to *Course* is called "course").

Comment: But how do I point to the course that was selected in the previous screen?

Comment: One way is to add a property "course" to the second view controller and set the value in didSelectRowAtIndexPath or prepareForSegue or whatever you use to move to the second view controller. (Actually that is quite a different question. If you google for "set property in another view controller" you will find a lot of information.)

Comment: So here is my prepareForSegue in the ClassList table view: if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showAddStudents"]) {
        AddStudentsTableViewController *addStudents = (AddStudentsTableViewController *) [segue destinationViewController];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        Course *selectedCourse = (Course *)[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        addStudents.currentCourse = selectedCourse;
        [addStudents setManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext]; Where would I send the selected row?

Comment: If I understand your code correctly then you already set the selected course: `addStudents.currentCourse = selectedCourse;`. Then you can use `Course *theCourse = self.currentCourse` in the code from my answer.

Comment: Everything seems to be working, but the fetched results controller is not returning any data. No crashes or errors, but also no data. Thanks for the help so far!

Comment: @JohnVanPatten: What happens if you *don't* set the predicate? Do you get all students or none?

Comment: @JohnVanPatten: Make sure that the relationship "course" from Student to Course is defined correctly (as inverse relationship to "students" from Course to Student). Verify that the Student objects have the "course" property set.

Comment: I checked the Course and Student .h and .m files, and the relationship property was not there, so that's got to be it. I'm going to scrap the app and start it over from scratch (I haven't gotten very far into it anyway). Thanks so much for your help!!!!